# Make the selection become the button you click

Tags: front-end, gui-construction

Let's assume I want a button that, when you click it, get the cell that contains it selected.
This approach won't work, it selects the cell containg the selection previous to the click.

```
Button["Select this cell", SelectionMove[ButtonNotebook[], All, Cell]]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
Button["Select this cell", SelectionMove[ButtonNotebook[], All, EvaluationCell]]
```

Comment: This is better than mine. +1

Comment: @halirutan I just browsed the help  ... beginner's luck :)

Answer (score 1):

What you could use is `NotebookFind` to search inside your notebook for something unique which distinguishes your `Button` from all other.

Here I looked at the cell-structure of your `Button` and used it to make a small function which creates exactly this button-cell with the exception, that it adds a `CellTag`. The `Button` itself just searches for this `CellTag` and selects the `Cell` where it is found. As a unique string I used simply the creation-time of the button:

```
MakeSelectionButton[] := With[{t = DateString[]},
  CellPrint@Cell[BoxData[
      ButtonBox["\<\"Select this cell\"\>",
        Appearance -> Automatic,
        ButtonFunction :> NotebookFind[
            ButtonNotebook[], t, All, CellTags],
        Evaluator -> Automatic,
        Method -> "Preemptive"]], "Output", CellTags -> t]
  ]

MakeSelectionButton[]
```